# Merge or group rows corresponding to particular column postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to group by the resultset further corresponding to the price_type column,
if the data for a product with both price_type variant and parent_product is present, then it must show only the variant one

For example, this data

```
Product Name  PPID   QTY   PRID  PRICE   PRICE_TYPE 
Shorts         1     10     21    200    variant
Shorts         1     10     21    100    parent_product
Night Suit     1     10     22    200    variant
Night Suit     1     10     22    100    parent_product
Denim          1     10     23    400    parent_product
```

should come like

```
Product Name  PPID   QTY   PRID  PRICE   PRICE_TYPE 
Shorts         1     10     21    200    variant
Night Suit     1     10     22    200    variant
Denim          1     10     23    400    parent_product
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want `row_number()` with *conditional* ordering:

```
select *
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by ProductName 
                                     order by (case when Price_type = 'variant' 
                                                    then 0 else 1
                                               end)
                                  ) as seq
       from table
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simple query to get desired result.

```
select
  distinct on(product_name),
  t.*
from tab t
order by price_type='variant' desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (
   SELECT * , 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product_name ORDER BY priority ) AS rank 
   FROM (
          SELECT *, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN price_type='variant' THEN 1 
                 ELSE 2 
               END AS priority 
          FROM yourtable
        ) AS X
  ) AS Y 
WHERE rank=1
```